Xubuntu 24.04 problems of languages with Thunar folders
When I install Xubuntu 24,04 in my language, the installation stays in English (before the new installer, it used to be installed directly in the user language).
Anyway, you can still change the language (and Regional preferences) and reboot.
But even so, Thunar folders name (or Nautilus or something else) is still in English (The rest is OK).
xdg-user-dirs-update doesn’t work even if user-dirs.locale is ok and includes fr_FR
Editing "user-dirs.dirs" doesn’t work either and makes a mess.
Anyone has the same thing or an idea of what to do ?
PS : I contacted the developers of Thunar (https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/-/issues/1417) but apparently it comes from user-dirs.dirs
Where could I report this bug ?

How to solve (not user friendly at all...)

Create the folders in your language
Edit the $HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs (Be aware that .config is hidden and
you should display hidden files)
Reboot
Delete the old files in
English

